# Como crear un scroll view horizontal que se mueva automaticamente y ciclicamente

Tags: android, android-studio, scroll

Estoy tratando de hacer un `scrollview` horizontal el cual va a llevar varias imágenes, lo que estoy tratando de hacer es que el `scroll` se mueva automáticamente y que cuando llegue al final vuelva a comenzar automáticamente desde la primera imagen algo así

http://sogamoso.org/turismo/turcom/Sogamoso.html, por ahora no tengo mas código que un `scrollvew` horizontal con algunos `imagebuttons`, les agradecería me ayudaran a solucionar este problema.

Código de `scroll`

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton12"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton11"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_transporte" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton10"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_industria" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton9"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_hoteles" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_contactanos" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_compartir" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_bar_coffe" />
    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: Me suena a que puedes usar mejor un ViewPager para lo que quieres hacer, el ViewPager puedes hacer una funcion para que pueda ir ciclando entre las imagenes. Saludos!

Comment: Voy a investigar por ese lado, gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final lo solucione utilizando esta libreria

https://github.com/firdausmaulan/GlideSlider

Answer (score 0):

Existe el metodo HorizontalScrollView y dentro de el colocas todos tus archivos.

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    // Aqui colocas tus objetos o elementos en un layout Horizontal

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: La idea es que las imagenes de scroll se muevan solas y ciclicamente

Answer (score 0):

Para un contenedor genérico, prueba con esto:

```
<HorizontalScrollView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingHorizontal="@dimen/common_padding_min"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        ...
```

Dentro del linerar layout puedes insertar las imágenes y mover con gestos desde kotlin.
También puedes evitar el scrollView y sustituir por un recyclerView.

**Alternativa a solo cambiar de elemento automáticamente.**
Usa un ViewPager, y cambia la pestaña por kotlin, algo así:

```
viewPager.currentItem = variable
```

where variable is a loop value from 0 to yourArray.size-1

Comment: Saludos, por favor explica como tu respuesta resuelve el problema de OP, las respuestas que son solo código son consideradas de baja calidad

Comment: Vale, actualizo mi respuesta...

Comment: Según leo OP quiere que sus imágenes se vayan moviendo automáticamente no tanto que el usuario tenga que moverlo con gestos. ;)

Comment: Vale, mi propuesta se enfocó en el contenedor genérico, pero actualizo mi respuesta para añadir una propuesta más puntual.